# Django- filtering of the filter object

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-filter

I want to make a complex filtering on the page using the FilterSets. This is my `Filterset`, nicely showing me tuples from chosen time and with chosen parameters.

```
# filters.py

class workFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    start__gt = filters.DateTimeFilter(name='time_start', lookup_expr='gte')
    start__lt = filters.DateTimeFilter(name='time_end', lookup_expr='lte')

    class Meta:
        model = Work
        fields = ('machine', 'program')
```

But I want to add charts explaining the queried data. For that I need informations, like overall count of time. I am querying them like that:

```
#views.py

def search(request):
    work_list = Work.objects.all()
    work_filter = workFilter(request.GET, queryset=work_list)
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)

    #some queries to add to context, such as
    sum_work = Work.objects.aggregate(Sum('time'))['time__sum']

    return render_to_response(
        TEMPLATE_DIRS + 'index.html',
        {
            'filter': praca_filter,
            'sum_work': sum_work,
        }
    )
```

But sadly, those queries are according to whole database, not to my filtered set of object.

How can I make queries on filtered set `work_filter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `sum_work` as a property of your `FilterSet`.

```
class WorkFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    start__gt = filters.DateTimeFilter(name='time_start', lookup_expr='gte')
    start__lt = filters.DateTimeFilter(name='time_end', lookup_expr='lte')

    class Meta:
        model = Work
        fields = ('machine', 'program')

    @property
    def work_sum(self):
        qs = super(WorkFilter, self).qs

        return qs.aggregate(Sum('time'))['time__sum']
```

Then when you pass your filter through to your view you just need `{{ filter.work_sum }}` in your template.